# Чтение данных из конкретного файла

Tags: javascript

Прочитать файл из файла можно, например, так: new FileReader (см. код ниже). Но этот метод требует выбора файла. Вопрос: как считать файл с известным именем?

```js
var tfile;
var reader = new FileReader();

function rdfile(files) {   
  tfile = files[0];
  reader.readAsText(tfile);
  alert(str); 
};

reader.onload = function(e) {
  str = e.target.result;
  alert(str);
};
```

Т.е. мне не надо выбирать файл, а надо явно указать в скрипте где он находится и какое его имя.

Comment: Так нельзя из соображений безопасности.

Comment: Не понятно. reader.readastext читает из файла tfile. Почему нельзя явно задать значение tfile указав конкретный файл?

Comment: @АлександрЯскович если бы можно было читать любой файл на компе пользователя... Вы представляете, что будет, если любой сайт, может прочитать **любой** файл на вашем жестком диске?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы это все работало только локально. Т.е. мне нужен код на javascript только для запуска на собственном компе. Неужели нельзя? Опять же не понятно: выбрать файл можно (используя FileReader), а явно задать нельзя.

Comment: js и так работает локально - это же происходит на стороне пользователя, у него на компьютере, нельзя открывать файлы без выбора файла, нельзя, понимаете? В целях безопасности вашего компьютера. Если бы можно было бы открыть файл или записать, зайдя на сайт или еще куда-то, вас бы напичкали вирусами и украли бы у вас ваши данные. Все просто как 2+2. Советую почитать https://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/ - спецификацию. Но если вы хотите у себя. поднимите node или другой серверный javascript.

Comment: какие конкретно файлы надо читать?

Answer (score 0):

Прочесть локальный текстовый файл с помощью javascript, с сервера, можно используя **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/files/textfile.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                readFile(data);
            }
        });
    });

    function readFile(allText) {
        var allLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        var out = [];
        for (var i=0; i<allLines.length; i++) {
                lines.push(allLines[i]);
        }
        console.log(out);
    }
```

---

Еще прочесть локальный CSV файл с сервера можно прочесть, используя библиотеку [d3](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#requests-d3-request), это очень удобно, потому что мы сразу можем получить объект с именами в заголовке, также использую данную библиотеку можно прочесть файлы форматов:`.tsv`, `.json` :

Пример Csv файла:

```
city,state,population,land area
seattle,WA,652405,83.9
new york,NY,8405837,302.6
boston,MA,645966,48.3
kansas city,MO,467007,315.0
```

Код:

```
d3.csv("/data/cities.csv", function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

Вывод в консоль:

> {city: "seattle", state: "WA", population: "652405", land area:
>   "83.9"}

---

Еще прочесть локальный текстовый файл можно использую NodeJs:

```
const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('./textfile.txt')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    console.log(line);
});
```

---

Прочесть локальный .js файл можно так:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

file.js:

```
var data = {1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: Вопрос: а можно пойти другим путем? Создать файл имеющий одну строку- var a=(1,2,3,4,5) и добавить  и js строку <script src="ссылка на файл"></script> объявив таким образом новую переменную(массив) и ее значение.

Comment: Json лучше создать

Comment: а так как вы написали, никто не делат, так не принято

Comment: <script src="data.js"></script> вот так еще можешь сделать, а внутри написать свои переменные